# MATE 18.10 Live CD on W10 Asus Zenbook (501VW) - hangs on boot

Tags: asus, 18.10, live-cd, ubuntu-mate

That I get a responsive grub menu means that the boot parameters are okay. Is this a valid assumption?

Is there a reliable mapping between the startup logo's progress indicator's dots and the stages of the  process or is the indicator simply polling for activity anywhere?

The bootup process survives one complete pass of the startup logo's progress indicator. What does this tell me?

The process does not get far enough that I can open a virtual terminal. Is there any other way I can look into the process? Perhaps additional boot parameters at the grub menu?

Here's so far:
The boot disk works successfully with another machine. But with the settings below:

- First boot device UEFI Generic Flash with 18.10
- Fast boot disabled
- CSM disabled or enabled (no difference)
- Secure boot disabled

The startup offers the grub menu. I choose 'Try' or if I choose 'Install' the startup logo runs the dots once then hangs with the first white dot lit.

I've seen that this machine is compatible with Ubuntu (with a couple niggles) so I hope there's something wrong with my 'BIOS' setup.

Answer (score 0):

Installation successful using the following :

```
 First boot device UEFI Generic Flash with 18.10
 Fast boot disabled
 CSM enabled 
 Secure boot disabled
```

The issue is apparently that the installer does not have the driver for the video card on board. To get around that:

At the Grub menu,

- select the option to install
- press 'e' at the option to install.
- move cursor down to the boot parameter line and at the end of that line enter nomodeset` and proceed with the boot.

With nomodeset the installation screens were mildly distorted but readable and responsive. The installer loaded the correct drivers and all is now well.